# ReflectionTypeLoadException Unable to load one or > more of the requested types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, appdomain

I have the following code , that loades all aseemblies that are refrenced by my porject and all referenced used by them

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && (typeof (MyType).IsAssignableFrom(t)));


foreach (var type in types.Where(type => typeof (MyType).IsAssignableFrom(type)))
                {... do something ...}
```

On my dev box this works as expected , on other environment this causes an exception

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information.

Why is that exception thrown ?
is it possible to refactor my code to make it so that exception is ignored ?

Comment: Using something like this to dump it `catch(ReflectionTypeLoadException e) { throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load type due to the following:{0}{1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.LoaderExceptions.Select(le => le.ToString()).ToArray()))); }`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the environment where this occurred for next couple of days . so Trying to solve it blind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same issue but the Assembly it was having issues with I didn't really care about.

I went from this (worked locally):

```
Type t = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
              .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
              .Where(a => a.FullName == clientEx.ExceptionType)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

To this:

```
Type t = null;

foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Type type in a.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.FullName == clientEx.ExceptionType)
            {
                t = type;
                break;
            }                                            
        }

        if (t != null)
            break;
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to load implementing types from current assembly so here's what worked for me.

```
var types = (typeof(ClassinAssembly).Assembly)
                                            .GetTypes()
                                            .Where(x => typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
                                            .ToList();

foreach (var t in types)
{
  .....
}
```